# Asp.net Gridview row click called not voluntarily when button on row is clicked

Tags: asp.net, gridview, onclick

I'm having trouble with this piece of code

> e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
>   Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" +
>   e.Row.RowIndex);

This is working fine when i click on the row but it's causing me troubles when i click on a button on this row because it start doing the button logic but then it does the click on the row.

I would like to know how to make the row clickable but not when i click on one of the buttons inside of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table input").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great! it worked.. didn't think at that haha thankyou!